# Why isn't this a basis for $P^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Explain why S is not a basis for P<sup>2</sup>. S = {1 + x<sup>2</sup>, 1 - x<sup>2</sup>}

I am having a difficult time putting into words why I don't think S is a basis and I think it is due to my lack of understanding of polynomials. I understand from a matrix point of view, but not from a polynomial point of view.

Matrix View:
Transform polynomial into aug. matrix.

1 + 0x + x<sup>2</sup> = 0
1 + 0x - x<sup>2</sup> = 0
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\1&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}

RREF
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}
Clearly this transformed into RREF because there are too many elements in the matrix.

How is this connected to polynomials? Does it simply mean that there is a free variable (and which variable is free, x or x<sup>2</sup>?) Can either of the variables be free? This is where my understanding falls apart.

Comment: What do the matrices stand for? ////I would prefer to explain that by definition of "basis", not others.

Comment: That can't have been what $S$ is supposed to be.

Comment: oops, there is a typo, second polynomial should have been -. I fixed it

Comment: The "matrix view" does not make sense to me.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I was doing things wrong by making 1 + x<sup>2</sup> == 1 + 0x + x<sup>2</sup>. That is false. It is really 1 + 0 + x<sup>2</sup> == 1 + x<sup>2</sup>. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: LaTeX > HTML....

Comment: What is the LaTeX code I should be using? I thought I was already using LaTeX here not HTML...

Comment: `$x^2$` is $x^2$, for example

Answer (score 3):

$P^2$ is three dimensional.   But $S$ only has two elements.

Alternatively,  $x\not\in\operatorname{span} S$.  Try to prove this...

Comment: I see my mistake. I assumed S has 3 elements by thinking that 1 + x2 == 1 + 0x + x2